# Convertir de Binario a Decimal en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hace un tiempo estuve buscando como resolver este problema en JavaScript, esta es la forma que mas me gustó, junto con una pequeña explicación, espero les sea útil.

Para convertir de Binario a Decimal, tomando como ejemplo el ´100´ debemos tener en cuenta la siguiente tabla:

Base para la conversión

sí binario es:  0 0 0 1 0 0

base es:    ........    2 2 2 2 2 2

potencia es:    5 4 3 2 1 0

posición array  [  ..   0 1 2]

esto significa que nuestra operación matemática es:

```
1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 =
  4   +   0   +   0   = 4
```

1. var array = num.split(''); => para recorrer num con un ciclo for,
   hay que separarlo ya que el parámetro que le pasemos a la función es
   un string, en este caso '100'.
2. var sum = 0; => necesitamos una variable para realizar la suma de
   las posiciones.
3. Recorremos el array con un for.
4. Math.pow => devuelve la base (en
   este caso 2 por ser binario) elevada al exponente.

```js
function binarioADecimal(num) {

  var array = num.split('');
  var sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + Math.pow(2, array.length - 1 - i) * array[i];
  }
  return sum;
};
console.log(binarioADecimal('100'));
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. SI la idea es compartir algo que descubriste como una pregunta autorrespondida, la forma ideal es que plantees la pregunta/problema y abajo, en el campo Tu Respuesta, pongas la solución que descubriste. Así podrán otros votar sobre la relevancia y tú mismo podrás marcarla como aceptada. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Mucho más fácil, usar el método estático del objeto Number

```
Number.parseInt( "11110",2 )
```

O en forma abreviada:

```
parseInt( "11110",2 )
```